# CCH iFirm and DocuSign integration

Tags: integration, docusignapi

Since I started using CCH iFirm and DocuSign I have not been able to send documents to clients as the integration has not yet been set up.

Any help to resolve this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you will get much help here. You would need to contact your support department.

Answer (score 0):

if an integration already exists between the two products, then you need to find it and have someone install/configure it. Start with your contacts at both companies.

If a new integration is needed, ask both companies about it. But if you want it sooner, you'll need to create it.

Contact your IT department and the professional services departments of both companies for proposals.